# I am confused about the meaning of this sentence

Tags: meaning

I am getting ready for the TOEFL exam. I saw this sentence in TPo.

> In late seventeenth-century Europe, what had been evolution in population followed by stabilization changed to population revolution.

I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Is that sentence copied **exactly** as written? It does not make grammatical or logical sense.

Comment: It would have made sense if 'revolution' were 'explosion' but I agree, as is, it is fairly confusing.

Comment: I too am confused. It's written like a question, but it's got the wrong tenses and is missing words that would make it one.

Comment: We can find the source on various websites https://t.weixue100.com/toefl/read/1437/4783.html It isn't a question (OP had been confused and inserted a question mark)

Comment: In late seventeenth-century Europe, what had been evolution in population followed by stabilization, changed to population revolution. A comma makes it clear. The grammar is fine. No issues at all.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very badly worded grammatically correct sentence.

The writer wants to say that in the past population grew slowly. They chose "evolution" to describe that growth. Evolution is slow, but it's not idiomatic to use it to describe growth. It is similarly nonidiomatic to use "revolution" for fast growth. "Explosion" would be correct.

Comment: This answer is correct.  Evolution can mean "slow improvement" or "slow transformation", but it doesn't mean "slow growth".  Revolution can mean "rapid replacement", but it doesn't mean "rapid growth".  The writer didn't understand the meaning of the words they used.

Comment: After reading the full article, I believe they did actually know what evolution and revolution mean.  Their mistake was that they believed that "population" could mean "population growth rate".  An evolution in population growth rates (meaning the rates were changing slowly), followed by a later revolution in population growth (a fundamental and permanent change in how population grew), makes more sense.    It's just that something like "population revolution" implies the population (the people themselves) changed, not the population growth.

Comment: @windblade Yes, they might have evo/revolution right and conflate population with population growth. In either case it's a poor example for teaching English, unless the purpose is to teach how to parse bad writing.

Answer (score 1):

> In late seventeenth-century Europe,

This tells you the date and place: Europe of the 1690s (roughly)

> what

This pronoun means "the thing that", and (as we soon see) the "thing" is "the changes in population"

> had been evolution in population followed by stabilization

Previously the *thing* was "slow growth, followed by no growth"

> changed to population revolution.

Then the *thing* became a rapid growth in population.

So the overall understanding is that the population rapidly grew in Europe in the 1690s, having not grown much in the previous centuries.  And (as we later learn) this is in part due to the cultivation of potatoes.

You can use this kind of structure:

> What was a caterpillar, is now a butterfly.

This isn't a question, although the use of "what" can be confusing.  It means the same as

> The thing that was a caterpillar is now a butterfly.